# Java abstract class - how can I best solve this?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I have an abstract class 'TopHandler'. There are two classes that extends TopHandler: 'UserHandler' and 'MerchantHandler'.

I have a method sendMessage() which I'm unsure where to place. One option is to put it inside TopHandler and create an object of either UserHandler or MerchantHandler, like this:

```
public abstract class TopHandler {

    //Other methods... 

    public void sendMessage() {

        TopHandler handler;
        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("User")) {
            handler = new UserHandler();
            //Call UserHandler implementation of abstract methods
        } else {
            handler = new MerchantHandler();
            //Call MerchantHandler implementation of abstract methods 
        }
    }
}
```

My other option is to make sendMessage() abstract and have both classes implement it, but this does create some duplicate/very similar code.

Comment: IMO your structure is good enough... maybe you want to check [FactoryPattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm)

Comment: depends on whether both subclasses need it, and how it is needed. shoudld it be static? dependent on the instance? dependent on the type ???

Comment: I find it weird that `TopHandler#sendMessage()`is not static but is used to instanciate a `TopHandler`. But I don't have a full view of your code. Anyway, another solution could be to have an abstract `TopHandler#createHandler()` method that would return the correct handler for each subclass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal opinion is that a class should not be aware of its subclasses.

What would happen if you create another class that inherit from `TopHandler`?
You will need to change the behaviour of your `TopHandler` class instead of simply overriding the method in your sub class.

You can find other opinion [here on programmers stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/219543/should-a-class-know-about-its-subclasses)

To answer your issue, the solution is simple: overide the method in each subclasses. If there is duplication, try to refactor your classes to move most of it in the `TopHandler` class.

That could be something like:

```
public abstract class TopHandler {

    //Other methods... 

    public void sendMessage() {
        TopHandler handler = createHandler();
        //Call Handler implementation of abstract methods
    }

    public abstract TopHandler createHandler();
}
```

PS: as a non static method, it feel weird that `sendMessage` instanciate a new `TopHandler`. You may have something wrong here. Maybe you just need to use `this` instead of a new handler (but it's hard to say as we don't have the full code).

Answer (score 2):

I would call an explicit factory method to make it clear that this is what it is doing.

```
static TcpHandler create(String mode) {
    return mode.equalsIgnoreCase("user") ? new UserHandler() : new MerchantHandler();
}
```

You can then call this method in your instance code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to adhere to the strategy design pattern and declare sendMessage() in TopHandler abstract,. And then implement the method in both UserHandler and MerchantHandler classes.

The reason  for this: suppose this code has to be extended then one can simply add another class extending TopHandler and implement all inherited  methods and test the new class. If one has to change the original TopHandler  class then that class would have to be tested as well.

Also readability is better when this method is implemented in each subclass.

Answer (score 0):

You should make `sendMessage()` abstract and implement them in both classes. And try to move duplicate codes into a separate method inside `TopHandler`class.

Because it is not good to know about child class inside parent class. Parent class should contain only common codes which is usable in every child classes.

you can read about abstract class [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/abstract-classes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since `sendMessage()` is defined in `TopHandler` and is not static, I assume that when you call it you already have a concrete implementation (either `UserHandler` or `MerchantHandler` instance) to call it on.

First, don't create any more instances in `sendMessage()` in that case.

Keep `sendMessage()` in `TopHandler` and non-abstract, and create abstract methods in `TopHandler` for every implementation-specific method you use in `sendMessage()`. that way, the common implementation will be kept in `TopHandler`, avoiding code duplication, and only the specifics will be implemented in the subclasses.

---

Alternatively, if your intention was for `sendMessage()` to be static - in that case:

- Making it abstract is not an option
- The first part is essentially a factory pattern (and could be separated into it's own method for clarity)
- The actual sending should be done only once (not in every condition's branch) and using (possibly abstract) methods of `TopHandler`

Answer (score 0):

The presence of `if/else` code that checks for type tells you that you're doing it wrong.  That's what inheritance and polymorphism were born to eliminate.

If `Handler` subclasses need to do something different in `sendMessage()`, then the abstract class either needs to provide a sensible default or make the method abstract.

The factory/virtual constructor recommendations are spot on.